# Python Sending outlook emails with signature

Tags: python, windows, outlook, win32com, office-automation

First time poster, long time reader

I've just upgraded my Python to 3.11 and now when I run my scripts to send emails, they take ages (4 minutes) to appear in the Drafts folder rather than actually send.  Is it just me, or are others having this issue too?

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')

mail         = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To      = 'email@address'
mail.Subject = 'Quick Email'

mail.GetInspector
index  = mail.HTMLbody.find('>', mail.HTMLbody.find('<body'))
Footer = mail.HTMLbody[index + 1:]

mail.HTMLbody =  mail.HTMLbody[:index + 1]
mail.HTMLBody += "Something"
mail.HTMLBody += Footer

mail.send
```

This (or something similar) was sending emails with signature imported from outlook with embedded pictures until a few weeks ago!

Comment: Is Outlook running at the time your code is executed?

Comment: Any kind of error text generated? The property is `HTMLBody` with an uppercase `B`. Your code is switching in between `B` and `b`. `win32com` may initially accept either or both: but later will only recognise `B`. The error text would help determine if this might be the case here.

Comment: Outlook is running.

Comment: No error text.  Looks like the program ran OK, but no email received.  After a few minutes the email is "delivered" to the Drafts folder.   Not a massive issue when sending 1 email, but when I am sending multiple emails, a touch annoying.

I have changed code to:

```mail.display()
mail.send()```

But this causes the message to display, screen to flash, user to get annoyed!

Answer (score 0):

If Outlook is already running under a different security context, for example, if you run a script from a command line run with administrative permissions and Outlook is run under a user account (non-administrative) you will not be able to retrieve an application instance, even the following code doesn't make any sense:

```
try:
    app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
except:
    app = win32com.client.GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application')
```

Outlook is a singleton, so no matter what you do, it will always connect to the running instance. But the COM system will refuse to marshal COM objects between the two processes run under different security contexts.

> Probably should have mentioned that I want to include the signature from my outlook account to the email contents

If you need to include the default signature you need to call the `Display` method of the `MailItem` to get the item displayed and let the signature be added to the item before you start adding anything to the `HTMLBody` property.